# Importing a specific node module 'bsv' to react app does not work any ideas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

When I remove the import for the module of 'bsv' in the below code and when I start the react app it shows the h1 tag.

However when I try to import the node module of 'bsv' and when I start the app it shows a blank white page

```
import React from "react";
const bsv = require("bsv");

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Wallet Workshop</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

package.json file is also showing the required dependencies.

```
"bsv": "^2.0.10",
```

Comment: Open the developer console to see if there is any error messages

Comment: @RickyMo nothing showosi n the developer console, its just blank

Comment: @RickyMo could it be something to do with webpack 5 overrides ? as i have to manually pollyfill the module?